# Legally speaking, can I copy fonts from our Macs to all of our windows computers? We are a public library

Tags: fonts, legal, font-licensing, licensing

Our marketing department decided they want to use Avant Garde in promotional items for the library. i.e., Newsletters, brochures, etc. Apart from marketing, who use macs and/or have Adobe fonts, no one else has access to Avant Garde.

I thought about copying the font files from one of the macs and installing them on all of our machines but started wondering about whether or not that would be legal to do.

We are a public library and the font would only be used for library promotional items.

I don't know if any of this matters when it comes to licensing. Any help?

Comment: This varies by typeface. A simple search brings up ( https://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-avant-garde-gothic/licenses# ).

Comment: It really depends if you have a "Server" license or a "Per Seat" license. *Typically*, cross-platform transfers are not permitted either way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question involves legal advice we cannot give you

Answer (score 1):

There's a [freeware clone of Avant Garde in light and bold weights](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/TeX-Gyre-Adventor) called TeX Gyre Adventor. I recommend using this as the easiest substitute. It has one limitation: it doesn't include the [crazy alternate capital ligatures](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/686869380637944110/?d=t&mt=login) of Avant Garde.† But it's the easiest simple option.

A very good option if you want to pay a little more is [Avalon](https://fontsite.com/font-library/avalon/), which is based on Avant Garde and includes all the weights. It's $13.95 for 5 computers and 14 styles, which is excellent value. Both of these are based on digitizations of ITC Avant Garde renamed for legal reasons. (Font designs aren't trademarked, although their names are.)

Back to your original question-IANAL. Macs don't come with ITC Avant Garde, they would have been bought with some software package. You probably want to look at where that software package came from and its licensing. It may be cross-platform and you may be able to install it on another computer; it may not.

One thing to point out to your bosses is that if you're not your organization's professional graphic designer, you shouldn't need to use the corporate fonts. It's quite common for organizations to use one font for branding and marketing and another (e.g. Arial) for internal communications which doesn't need to be to such a high design standard. Indeed there are good reasons for this; basic fonts like Arial and Times New Roman have bulletproof character sets which cover most major languages (e.g. correct spelling of Czech, Vietnamese and Polish authors' names); branding fonts often don't.

† And its italics aren't great, they just seem to have been auto-slanted. But that's [unfortunately true of the current main digitization](http://typographica.org/on-typography/aint-what-itc-used-to-be/) of Avant Garde too. Avalon's italics are better than either.

Comment: there have been arguments made that a too-similar typeface for a document proper "dilutes" the logo impact. Brand documents often specify a proper "off the shelf" pairing for use as copy text.

Comment: I dont agree that nondesigners do not need corporate fonts. It depends entirely of how much forward facing documentation they make.

Comment: Non-designers very often do create external communication as well – invoices, order specifications, letters to clients, things like that. And there are lots of businesses that have specific templates and branding fonts for that. So yeah, I too disagree that you “shouldn’t need to use the corporate fonts” unless you’re the graphic designer. There’s a good chance you don’t need to use the _logotype_ font, but corporate fonts are more than just what’s in the logo.

Comment: Yeah, sure, I get that. Was more thinking that the OP seemed to be terrified they would lose their job if they didn't make everything use the brand font marketing insist on.

Comment: >>  (Font designs aren't trademarked, although their names are.)
As I recall, that's true in the US, but may not be in Europe or other parts of the world. Nitpicky, I know, and not likely a concern of OPs. The company that created the knock-off typeface might be subject to lawsuits, though.